# Delegate Not Called in UICollectionReusableView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, delegates, uicollectionreusableview

I have a single custom `UICollectionReusableView` as a `UICollectionView` header.  Inside this view, I have two buttons.  I have created a delegate method to perform the button actions however they are not being called.

I add my header in the `UICollectionViewDataSource` as follows;

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.exploreCollectionReusableView, for: indexPath) as! ExploreCollectionReusableView
    return headerView
}
```

I set up my protocol methods and add a delegate variable inside the custom header;

```
protocol SelectedDidSeeAll {
    func seeAllCategories()
    func seeAllItems()
}

var delegate: SelectedDidSeeAll?
```

I add the targets to the buttons;

```
seeAllCategoriesButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(seeAllCategories), for: .touchUpInside)
seeAllItemsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(seeAllItems), for: .touchUpInside)
```

I set the delegate to be self in the `UIViewController` `viewDidLoad()`

```
exploreCollectionReusableView.delegate = self
```

I implement the `@objc` functions;

```
@objc func seeAllCategories() {
    delegate?.seeAllCategories()
}

@objc func seeAllItems() {
    delegate?.seeAllItems()
}
```

Lastly, I conform to the delegate method in the `UIViewController`;

```
extension ExploreViewController: SelectedDidSeeAll {

func seeAllCategories() {
    // Do Something
    print("something")
    }

func seeAllItems() {
    // Do Something
    print("something")
    }
}
```

### Delegate Console Log

When printing the delegate I get;

```
Optional(<bidr.ExploreViewController: 0x7fd466e5d0b0>)
```

So I assume I have done everything necessary to implement the delegate method, however, clicking the buttons has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `viewDidLoad()`, set the `delegate` in `collectionView(_: viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind: at:)`, i.e.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.exploreCollectionReusableView, for: indexPath) as! ExploreCollectionReusableView
    headerView.delegate = self
    return headerView
}
```

In `viewDidLoad()`, the `exploreCollectionReusableView` might not be set.

Comment: My dataSource is a custom UICollectionViewDataSource class therefore, its not possible.

Comment: Then pass the ViewController's instance in dataSource and use that to set the delegate.